# Replace words in a string using reference from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 dictionaries and want to replace values in the SQL query using as reference the other dictionary:

```
params_to_replace = {'tvchview': [{'source': 'table', 'channel': ['abc', 'abcd']}],
                     'tvtot_du': [{'source': 'table1', 'channel': ['ab']}]} 

queries = {'tvchview': 'SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN (${channel});',
           'tvtot_du': "SELECT id, SUM(duration) AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN ('${channel}') GROUP BY id;"}
```

The desired output is:

```
{'tvchview': 'SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM table WHERE channel IN ('abc', 'abcd');',
 'tvtot_du': "SELECT id, SUM(duration) AS value FROM table1 WHERE channel IN ('ab') GROUP BY id;"}
```

This is where I got, but don't know to to proceed. I am not sure if the last two lines are needed. I wanted to split the string and to replace the words, but not sure if this is the best way. Also there can be a case the references may be other words not only source and channel, basically anything from the dictionary should be replaced:

```
for k, v in queries.items():
    if k in params_to_replace:
        for v1 in params_to_replace.values():
            res = {k: v for d in v1 for k, v in d.items()}
            a = [el.split() for el in list(queries.values())]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```py
params_to_replace = {
        'tvchview': [{'source': 'table', 'channel': ['abc', 'abcd']}],
        'tvtot_du': [{'source': 'table1', 'channel': ['ab']}]
    }

queries = {
        'tvchview': 'SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN (${channel});', 
        'tvtot_du': "SELECT id, SUM(duration) AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN ('${channel}') GROUP BY id;"
    }

expected_output = {
        'tvchview': "SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM table WHERE channel IN ('abc', 'abcd');",
        'tvtot_du': "SELECT id, SUM(duration) AS value FROM table1 WHERE channel IN ('ab') GROUP BY id;"
    }

for k, v in params_to_replace.items():

    # Because the tvchview has => (${channel}) and 
    # The tvtot_du has => ('${channel}') in the queries dictionary
    if k == 'tvtot_du':
        queries[k] = queries[k].replace("${source}", v[0]['source']) \
                    .replace("${channel}", ", ".join(item for item in v[0]['channel']))
    else:
        queries[k] = queries[k].replace("${source}", v[0]['source']) \
                    .replace("${channel}", ", ".join("'" + item + "'" for item in v[0]['channel']))

print(queries == expected_output)
```